# how to write E2E tests for search feature

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I've a feature in my application where the data collection be created dynamically by a job that runs nightly (it collects data from sql and creates a mongo collection). I've created a page to search the data from that collection and upon clicking the results it will take the user to edit the data and then save it back. As, my test database in different than my actual database how can I test this feature, any idea or inputs from anyone is highly appreciated. I can copy my collection from my dev database to my test database, but I'm wondering how do I that when I run my tests in my CI environment.

Answer (score 0):

Build cleanup functions to ensure that your environment is the same every time you run the tests.

In protractor you just need to send keys to whatever search box you have created.

Sorry I'll need more info in order to give more useful advice. Try [protractortest.org](http://protractortest.org)